# Indefinite integral of $\cos^{3}(x) \cdot \ln(\sin(x))$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help. I have to integrate $\cos^{3} \cdot \ln(\sin(x))$ and I don´t know how to solve it.  In our book it is that we have to solve using the substitution method. If somebody knows it, you will help me..please

Comment: substitute $u(x)=\sin(x)$

Comment: How can you use Pythagorean trigonometric identity to procede with Blah's method?

Comment: The expression is meaningless as written; is that first factor supposed to be $\cos^3 x$?

Comment: I think you mean $\cos^3x\log(\sin x)$. Is that what you want to integrate?

Comment: Oh, I sorry, I forgot argument of the function x, of course I thought cos^{3}x* ln(sin x). I've counted, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Substitute :

$\sin x =t \Rightarrow \cos x dx =dt$ , hence :

$I=\int (1-t^2)\cdot \ln (t) \,dt$

This integral you can solve using integration by parts method .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $\cos^3 x\ln(\sin x)$, let $u=\sin x$. Then $du=\cos x dx$, and $$\begin{align*}
\cos^3 x\ln(\sin x)dx&=\cos^2 x\ln(\sin x)\Big(\cos x dx\Big)\\
&=\cos^2 x\ln u \,du\\
&=(1-\sin^2 x)\ln u\,du\\
&=(1-u^2)\ln u\,du\;,
\end{align*}$$

which can be integrated by parts.